# iterm shell integration not integrating

Tags: bash, ssh, iterm

I'm trying to switch to iterm from terminal. I install latest iTerm2 (3.1.5), select iTerm2 in the top left hand corner, and click 'Install Shell Integration'. Basically, I followed these instructions [here](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html).

Next, I create a profile for my ssh called 'foo' and drop the command in the ~/.bash_profile with the following line.

```
alias foo='set_iterm_profile foo; ssh heyo@foo.edu'
```

I exit the shell and open a fresh one. And type

```
$ foo
```

Immediately, I get a response.

```
-bash: set_iterm_profile: command not found
```

Something must have gone wrong with the integration. So, I check my ~/.bash_profile and see

```
test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash"
```

Cool. Looks good to me. Does the file even exist?

```
ll ${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash
/Users/me/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash
```

Yes it does! I close the shell and try again. I even install a different version. Same result.

Why can't I get iterm's shell integration integrated?

System: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Answer (score 0):

```
set_iterm_profile() { echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=$1\a"; }
```

For whatever reason I believed this command to be related to iTerm, but it's actually a bash function that needed to be set. The link that save my life....

https://coderwall.com/p/s-2_nw/change-iterm2-color-profile-from-the-cli